button doesn't redirect Primefaces and java 7
My button doesn't redirect me to my case inquiry page; it seems like it's thinking and shows a ball wanting to do it, but it stays on the same pending signature screen. However, upon debugging, I see that it does not enter the method. The lazy model, where I display the cases pending signature, is a custom model. But I don't understand why it doesn't enter the method to redirect to the case inquiry page. How could I solve this?
It is my xhtml:
<p:dataTable var="expediente"
                                value="#{peticionesPendientesBean.lazyModel}"
                                rowKey="#{expediente.mCodExpediente}"
                                sortBy="#{expediente.t0.valor}" sortOrder="DESCENDING" paginator="true"                                     
                                rows="10" rowIndexVar="index"
                                styleClass="desplegable"
                                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} 0 Seleccionados {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} "
                                rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100,200"
                                id="tblPendientes" lazy="true" emptyMessage="#{msg.tbl_noRegist}" widgetVar="widgetVarTable"
                                currentPageReportTemplate="#{peticionesPendientesBean.lazyModel.rowCount==1? lbl.tb_exp_pag : lbl.tb_exps_pag}">
                                                                                                    
                                <p:column headerText="#{lbl.titulo_peticiones_pendientes}"
                                    sortBy="#{expediente.t1.id_expediente}" sortable="true" id="codExpediente">
                                    <h:outputText
                                    value="#{expediente.getAtributo(nombreAtributos.CODEXPEDIENTE).value} " />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="#{lbl.estado}" 
                                    sortBy="#{expediente.t2.valor}" sortable="true">
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="#{configuracionBean.getEstado(expediente.mEstado).descripcion}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="#{lbl.doc_enviado_firma}" style="width:250px;">
                                    <h:outputText
                                        value="#{peticionesPendientesBean.getNombreDoc(expediente)}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="#{lbl.estado_pet}" style="width:240px;">
                                    <h:outputText value="#{peticionesPendientesBean.getEstadoMapeado(expediente)}" />
                                </p:column>
                                <p:column headerText="#{lbl.accion}">
                                    <p:commandButton value="#{lbl.bt_detalle}" id="btnAccion" process="@this"
                                        action="#{expedientesBean.seleccionaExpediente('consultar',expediente.mCodExpediente,'Reclamaciones','Reclamacion')}"
                                        update=":msgs" icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="#{lbl.accion}">
                                    </p:commandButton>
                                </p:column>
                                
                            </p:dataTable>

This is my bean:
@Named("expedientesBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ExpedientesBean extends BaseBean {

    protected static final ResourceBundle ERR = ResourceBundle.getBundle(Presentacion.RUTA_ERRORES);
    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -311237890540793258L;

    /**
     * Logger
     */
    protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExpedientesBean.class.getCanonicalName());

    @Inject
    protected transient MotorTramitacionBean clientMT;

    @Inject
    protected ConfiguracionBean configuracionBean;

    protected HashMap<String, Expediente> mapExpedientes;
    protected HashMap<String, GestorEntidad> mapGestorEntidad;

    protected HashMap<String, LazyDataModel<Expediente>> mapExpedienteBusqueda;

    protected List<String> listaVacia = new ArrayList<String>();

    private boolean isArchivado = false;

    @Inject
    protected transient GeneradorDocumento generadorDocumento;

    /**
     * Temporal
     */
    @Inject
    protected ParametroAtributos parametroAtributos;

    /**
     * Temporal
     */
    @Inject
    protected ParametroConfiguraciones parametroConfiguraciones;

    @Inject
    protected UserReclamacionesBean urb;

    public ExpedientesBean() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        mapExpedientes = new HashMap<String, Expediente>();
        mapGestorEntidad = new HashMap<String, GestorEntidad>();
        mapExpedienteBusqueda = new HashMap<String, LazyDataModel<Expediente>>();

    }

    public String seleccionaExpediente(final String nameSelector, final Long expSeleccionado, final String apl, final String proc) {
        String result = Cadenas.VACIO;
        try {
            final Expediente exp = clientMT.ExpedienteInformacion(apl, proc, expSeleccionado);
            this.mapExpedientes.put(nameSelector, exp);
            result = NavigationRules.EXPEDIENTE_CONSULTA;
        } catch (final MotorExpedienteException e) {
            this.addMessageErrorId(MessageId.IMPORTANT, Presentacion.ERROR_EXP_NO_EXISTE, Presentacion.ERROR_EXP_NO_EXISTE);
        }
        return result;
    }


Abovelinked duplicate enlists all possible causes why a button's action isn't invoked and includes additional debugging hints. Next time please try to create a [mcve] yourself. Copy the code into a separate project and remove as many as possible parts not contributing to the problem. For example styleClass="desplegable" and protected final Logger logger do absolutely not contribute to the observable problem. You should then not include this kind of noise in the question in order to make the actual problem better focused (also for yourself!). See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info
